# Pass a variable to the next template

Tags: python, django

I want to pass one variable throuth one template to another.
First template I identify the variable and go to the second. From second I want to pass this variable to the third template.

valoare-list.html

```
{% for valoare in valoares %}
     <a href="{% url 'valoare_detail' pk=valoare.pk %}">
          Contracte de valoare {{ valoare.tip_valoare }}
     </a>
{% endfor %}
```

valoare-detail.html

```
<!-- This variable to be sent to the next template -->
Valoare: {{ valoare.tip_valoare }} <br>

{% for tip in tips %}
      <a href="{% url 'contract_list' valoare=valoare.tip_valoare pk=tip.pk %}">
           Tip Contracte de {{ tip.tip_contract }}
      </a>
{% endfor %}
```

contract-list.html

```
Valoare: {{ valoare.tip_valoare }} <br>
Tip Contract: {{ tip.tip_contract }}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Valoare(models.Model):
    VALOARE_CHOICES = (
           ("MICA","mica"),
           ("MARE","mare"),
    )
    tip_valoare = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=VALOARE_CHOICES, default="MICI")
    file_name = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tip_valoare


class Tip(models.Model):
    TIP_CHOICES = (
           ("BUNURI","bunuri"),
           ("SERVICII","servicii"),
           ("LUCRARI","lucrari"),
    )
    tip_contract = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=TIP_CHOICES, default="BUNURI")
    file_name = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tip_contract
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Valoare, Tip


def valoare_list(request):
    valoares = Valoare.objects.all
    return render(request, 'contracte/valoare_list.html', {'valoares': valoares})

def valoare_detail(request, pk):
    valoare = get_object_or_404(Valoare, pk=pk)
    tips = Tip.objects.all
    return render(request, 'contracte/valoare_detail.html', {'valoare': valoare, 'tips': tips})

def contract_list(request, valoare, pk):
    (?????)
    tip = get_object_or_404(Tip, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'contracte/contract_list.html', {'valoare': valoare, 'tip': tip})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.valoare_list, name='valoare_list'),
    url(r'^valoare/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.valoare_detail, name='valoare_detail'),
    url(r'^contract/(?P<valoare>[a-z]{4})/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.contract_list, name='contract_list'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're passing `tip_valoare` through this: `<a href="{% url 'contract_list' valoare=valoare.tip_valoare pk=tip.pk %}">`, then the `valoare` value inside the url `url(r'^contract/(?P<valoare>[a-z]{4})/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ...)`, would be the `tip_valoare` (4 lower-case letters).

Then, you can get the `valoare` object like this (inside the `contract_list` view):

```
def contract_list(request, valoare, pk):
    # (?????) - valoare is actually the tip_valoare
    valoare = get_object_or_404(Valoare, tip_valoare=valoare)
    tip = get_object_or_404(Tip, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'contracte/contract_list.html', {'valoare': valoare, 'tip': tip})
```